# How to select date from mysql table by order record of another table

Tags: mysql, sql

My situation is this:
I have 2 mysql table: **user** and **scores**.

The table **user** is like that: id, name.
The table **scores** is like that: id, point, user_id;

I want to take the name of the 10 users that make the high scores, but i don't know what kind of query i have to use. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 4):

The simpliest answer for that is to use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` but it doesn't handle for duplicate users having the same point.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    user a
        INNER JOIN scores b
            ON a.id = b.user_ID
ORDER   BY b.point DESC
LIMIT   10
```

To handle duplicate points, you can have a subquery which contains the **top N** score.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    user a
        INNER JOIN scores b
            ON a.id = b.user_ID
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  point
            FROM    scores
            GROUP   BY point
            ORDER   BY point DESC
            LIMIT   10
        ) c ON b.point = c.point
ORDER   BY b.point DESC
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo** (*you can see the difference between the two queries*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9daaf/5)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use an `INNER JOIN` query and get all relevant data you need ordering by `points` column descending and limiting results to 10

```
SELECT *
FROM user a
LEFT JOIN scores b
ON a.id = b.user_id
ORDER BY b.point DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this:-

```
SELECT *
FROM user as u,scores as s Where u.id = s.user_id
ORDER BY s.point DESC
LIMIT 10
```